# Link Player Registration with Java Game

Tags: java, applet, registration, minecraft

So I am creating a Java Game Applet, with Netbeans. I was wondering how to have a PLAYER REGISTRATION PAGE, then link it so the player can login to the game.

Think of Minecraft. How do I go about that process of registering on a web page, then logging into the game (inside the game), if it is anything code related? Could anyone give some tips or pointers?

Comment: You basically need a server to keep the two in sync.

Comment: Way before the code, there is a question of design here I guess.

Comment: Could you refer me to a website that could help me? Or a website with a server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of something you could use: http://a1o1.posterous.com/java-fx20-embedding-webview-in-swing.

Basically, what you're asking for is embedding a webpage inside a Java Program, so it is a Webview of some sort. I would however suggest the possibility of creating a native Java interface and handling communications with your server yourself underneath, with whatever technology you like best (JSON, SOAP webservice, GET/POST...)

Therefore your program consists of two parts, a "server" part that manages player registration, with a database behind it, and a "game" part in Java, with a view that may be a webview or a native view, depending on your skills and wishes.

Edit:

You can for example run a Windows server with a Microsoft SQL 2008 database, running IIS7. You then could have a WCF webservice customerRegistration.svc that your java program calls.

You can also for example run a BSD server with Apache, with a MySQL database, and have a Webview in your app that calls a customerRegistration.php page.

These are both an ONLINE database, as per your comment. Both would work. If you can't understand this answers your issue.... start smaller and come back to this project later. You will increase your likelihood for success.

One more thing: CAPS IS YELLING. It's not cool.

Good luck.

Comment: I am talking about having an ONLINE database. I want to have players register on a webpage, then use their login info to log onto the game.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what @Jeremy Heiler and I are telling you. I'll edit my post to add an example.